# Terraform ec2 instance type on condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create spot instances on a condition from the .tfvars file. Otherwise I want a regular ec2 instance.
I know there's a ternary condition, but unsure how to properly use it.

```
spot = var.spot_instance ? instance_market_options {
    market_type = "spot"
  } :
```

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "test"
  }
  image_id = "ami-test"
  instance_market_options {
    market_type = "spot"
  }
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Or could it be this?

```
instance_market_options = var.spot_instance ? {
    market_type = "spot" 
  } :
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the code snippet does not seem like it's whole, this should look something like the following:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "test"
  }
  image_id = "ami-test"

  dynamic "instance_market_options" {
    for_each = var.spot_instance ? [1] : []
    content {
      market_type = "spot"
    }
  }
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

This is using a combination of [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta-argument and [`dynamic`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) block. Additionally, you cannot use any conditions in the `*.tfvars` files.

Comment: Do I still use for_each if spot_instance is just spot_instance = true in the *.tfvars files?

Comment: Yes, that's how you decide whether or not the `dynamic` block will be used or not.